# How does a ERC20 Token Smart Contract work?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, ether

I am having a hard time understanding smart contract and how they work on the network. I will be using an ERC20 token Smart Contract as an example:

```
contract EIP20 is EIP20Interface {
    uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;

    string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
    uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
    string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX

    function EIP20(
        uint256 _initialAmount,
        string _tokenName,
        uint8 _decimalUnits,
        string _tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
        name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }
```

My questions are:

1. How is this smart contract deployed on the network? Are tokens like objects that are instantiated from this contract?
2. In the constructor, it states "give all tokens to creator". Does that mean the Smart Contract is only run once and then just lives on the block chain. It couldn't be smart-contracts are like a class and tokens are like objects because then that would mean each token would have the ability to create their own supply amount.

I apologize for my lack of understanding. I come from an Object Oriented Background, and grasping the concept of Smart Contract has been a little difficult for me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**who is this smart contract deployed on the network? Are tokens like objects that are instantiated from this contract?**

A contract is just an account in ethereum's state tree. Every account has a balance, a nonce, bytecode, and the root hash of a storage tree. For normal accounts, the byte code and storage hash are empty. For contracts, the bytecode is the contract's code and the storage hash is the merkle root hash of all the key-value pairs in the contract's storage. The only thing that goes in the block are the transactions themselves, and the merkle root hash of the entire state tree. To be a full node tho, you must keep all the key-value pairs for the state tree (where keys are addresses and values are serialized accounts) and for the storage trees for each contract account (where the keys are storage locations and values are storage values).

EVM memory is transient. The EVM is not really a virtual machine (VM has a strong connotation for many) - it's just an interpreter for the EVM assembly language. As the interpreter runs, it maintains a stack (where each element is 32 bytes) and a memory byte-array, and has access to the contract's storage tree. The stack and memory byte-array are dropped when the execution completes. But yes, every single node runs the transaction - at any point in the execution, the state of the stack, the memory-byte array, the program counter, and the storage should be identical on each node.

Every node runs the interpreter for every transaction. It's just like bitcoin. Every node runs the little script that executes when you try to spend from a previously unspent output (assuming you know about bitcoin). The hash of the transaction isn't relevant until it is being stuffed into a merkle tree. When running the execution, all we care about is the amount of gas, the data being passed in, and the code of the contract that's being called. When the execution completes, the storage tree of the contract may be updated, so we recompute the merkle root hash of that tree (and any other contract which may have been called by that one!)

The state transition function has a series of parts. There's the part that updates account balances and nonces (the simple part), the part that handles gas and gas refunds, the part that executes EVM byte code (which can cause account balances and storage values to change), and the part that pays miners for mining blocks and uncles. This "function" is defined in detail in the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) and implemented independently in each of the ethereum clients (c++, go, python, etc). The EVM, or what I'm calling the interpreter, is typically just a for loop that increments a program counter and has a big switch statement telling it what to do for each operation in the byte code (pop/push the stack, load/store memory, load/store storage, call another contract, suicide, etc.)

source: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3k4h3w/basic_questions_about_the_ethereum_evm_and_state/

---

**Does that mean the Smart Contract is only run once and then just lives on the block chain.**

Every node in the network executes smart contract code for each transaction that you call it. So, smart contracts runs every time that you call it and change its state.
Every node has to verify the results of a transaction which invokes a smart contract. The result is that at least every full node will execute the code.

Take a look to ethereum development tutorial:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial